# How do I Execute Code after a Test failed

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mstest, vs-unit-testing-framework

I am Creating Unit Tests for a Library. This Library Connects to a Datasource and then I am doing some testing Stuff afterwards the Datasource will be disconnected.

> If one of the Tests fails, the Method is Terminated and I dont get to execute the Disconnection Function.

Here's a Sample to understande the above description:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Test()
{
    var datasourceObject = new DatasourceObject("location-string");
    datasourceObject.Connect();

    // Do some Stuff with Asserts

    datasourceObject.Disconnect(); // must be executed
}
```

#### Is There any Bestpractice to achieve that?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you use resource in other tests, then move it to class fields and use `[TestInitialize]` and `[TestCleanup]` to get and free that resource:

```
private Foo datasourceObject;

[TestInitialize]
public void TestInitialize()
{
    this.datasourceObject = new DatasourceObject("location-string");
    this.datasourceObject.Connect();
}

[TestMethod]
public void Test()
{
    // Do some Stuff with Asserts
}

[TestCleanup]
public void TestCleanup()
{
    this.datasourceObject.Disconnect();
}
```

If you use resource in this test only, then use either `try`..`finally`

```
[TestMethod]
public void Test()
{
    try
    {
        var datasourceObject = new DatasourceObject("location-string");
        datasourceObject.Connect();
        // Do some Stuff with Asserts
    }
    finally
    {
        datasourceObject.Disconnect(); // must be executed
    }
}
```

Or `using` statement if resource is disposable:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Test()
{
    using(var datasourceObject = new DatasourceObject("location-string"))
    {
        datasourceObject.Connect();
        // Do some Stuff with Asserts
    }
}
```

Comment: I am quite new to the UnitTest Framework.. I have looked up the `[TestInitialize]` and `[TestCleanup]` attributes, and it seems like that what I've been searching for. Thanks alot, will accept your answer as soon as I can :)

Comment: @LuckyLikey usually unit test frameworks have pairs of special methods which are executed before/after all tests, and before/after each test. E.g. in NUnit same methods should be marked with `Setup` and `TearDown` attributes

Comment: Thanks for the `try...finally` approach (for one test only)